# Find two numbers to minimize the sum of squares

Tags: statistics, optimization, least-squares

Suppose we are given a sequence of positive numbers
$0<a_1<a_2< \cdots < a_n$.

Step 1. Choose an integer $m$ where $m \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. After choosing $m$, we divide our numbers into two subgroups $\{a_1,\cdots,a_m\}$ and $\{a_{m+1},\cdots,a_n\}$.

Step 2. Given two numbers $a', a'' \in \mathbb{R}$,
we can calculate the sum of squares in the two subgroups
$$SS = \sum_{i=1}^{m} (a_i-a')^2+\sum_{j=m+1}^n (a_j-a'')^2.$$

My question is how to choose $m, a', a''$ to minimize the $SS$.

The $a'$ and $a''$ are easy to solve. In fact, $a'$ should be the mean of the first subgroup, i.e. $\frac{a_1+\cdots + a_m}{m}$ and $a''$
should be the mean of the second subgroup, i.e. $\frac{a_{m+1}+\cdots + a_n}{n-m}$.

To solve $m$, I guess that we can firstly compute the mean $\bar{a}$ of the whole group, i.e. $\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ and then $m$ should be the largest integer such that $a_m<\bar{a}$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: [Please don't cross-post.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/472576/1352) I'll flag your question on CV for a moderator's attention and ask them to migrate it here.

Comment: I doubt there's an analytic solution. That's [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) which is NP-hard in general Euclidean space (of d dimensions) even for two clusters.

Comment: @Its_me, for $k=2$ and $d=1$ (as in this question), $k$-means is $O(n^3)$.